# PHPWord : text color change doesn't work in output word document

Tags: textcolor, phpword

the text color in html doesn't work in output word document.

Here my code :

```
<?php
include_once 'Sample_Header.php';

// New Word Document
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Create new PhpWord object' , EOL;
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$html = '<p style="color:#FF0000;">Text color</p>';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);

// Save file
echo write($phpWord, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);
if (!CLI) {
    include_once 'Sample_Footer.php';
}
```

So why the text color change doesn't work in output word document ? An idea ?

Thank you in advance.